# How i can know if an Image will cause a php memory_limit error?

Tags: php, html, memory-limit

During the resize of an image I receive the error "Out of Memory" of PHP. I can solve it by set a greater value in my `php.ini` but what happens if I can't modify my `php.ini` (and also I can't set this value runtime with PHP) due webhosting security policy?

I upload the image using a normal post with `$_Files`, my `memory_limit` is 32 mb. How can I calculate if an image will cause this error during the resize? The uploaded photos may have different formats and weight; I’m trying to resize to an unique width of 820px.

EDIT

I have found this site http://www.dotsamazing.com/en/labs/phpmemorylimit
Maybe i have to replicate this calculation but it seems very hard to do.

Comment: If you can't alter php.ini or change memory_limit then you're pretty much stuffed and you should look for a more flexible hosting provider. Don't expect the average internet user to know how to resize their photos before they upload them.

Comment: What you should do is resize the image in the browser (using JS) and then upload the small image to the PHP script. That way if anyone gets an out of memory error, it would more likely be the browser.

Comment: what are you using to resize the image? are you using gd functions in php?

Comment: Yes i'm using gd to make the resize.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you would want to get the image size before you attempted to resize it.

For example once you have a temporary path for the file on the server, pass it to the function:

```
$image_size = getimagesize('/path/to/image');
```

This will provide you will lots of info about the image, including it's size.

Once you have tthis, then subtract your memory_limit, which you can get the value of with:

```
$my_memory_limit = ini_get('memory_limit');
```

So your available memory becomes

```
$memory_available = $my_memory_limit - $size;
```

At which point you can make the decision of whether you have the memory to resize it (depending on how memory costly your re size process is, or if you kick it back to the user and tell them to use a smaller image.

Comment: thank you for the answer but i wanna know if is possible to know the required memory to resize an image. The memory required for the resizing is greater than the memory occupied by the size of the image.

Comment: Ah I see, That would be dependent on the exact code to resize the image.  Typically using functions like "imagecreatefromjpeg" ... this would require a very intimate understanding of how your resize code is working.  However, the worst case scenario should be the image size times 2 (which would be resizing the image to the same size it is)